# Notation Concerning Improper Integral and the Absolute Value of an Integrand

Tags: calculus, notation

I have the following integral

$$\int_{- \infty}^\infty e^{-|x|} dx$$

Since the preimages $x$ determine the the images $e^{-|x|}$ for nonnegative and negatives preimages, I believe the integral must be evaluated in the following manner

$$\lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0} \enspace \int_{- \infty}^{c} e^{-|x|} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- |x|} \enspace dx$$

where $c$ obviously approaches $0$ without necessarily equalling $0$, so that $e^{- |x|} = e{-(-x)}$. So,

$$\lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0} \enspace \int_{- \infty}^{c} e^{-|x|} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- |x|} \enspace dx $$

$$= \lim \limits_{c \rightarrow 0} \enspace \int_{- \infty}^{c} e^{x} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \enspace dx $$

$$= 2$$

Also, I think it is wrong to write

$$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} \enspace dx \quad + \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- |x|} \enspace dx$$

Since the first integral includes the value $0$, causing discrepancies with $e^{-|x|}$.

This is more of a notation issue and I would like some insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to take limits here. The function has no singularities where it blows up to $\infty$ for any real value of $x$.

Since $e^{-|x|}$ is an even function, we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-|x|}=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}=2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since your integrand is bounded everywhere (including the origin) the question whether to consider $c=0$ is not so much the point, there is no limit process needed here. The question is how to include $\infty$ as a bound.

This is done ba defining $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx := \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \int_a^r f(x) dx$

And if you split an integral from $-\infty$ to $ \infty$ the you have to use the same point for splitting it, of course.

(For the so called Lebesgue integral all this is not an issue, only for the Riemann integral)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to be cautious with $x$ as $x \to 0$. If you want to use limits on this problem, I'd do it for the limits at infinity. You can also use the fact that the area under your curve is symmetric about the $y$ axis, leaving you to evaluate $$\lim_{N \to \infty} 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-|x|}\text{d}x $$ Restricting your interval of integration to $[0,\infty)$ will also let you drop the absolute value out of the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is needlessly complicated.  You can proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}\,dx & = \int_{-\infty}^0  e^{-|x|} \, dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-|x|} \, dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-(-x)} \, dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^x \, dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx
\end{align}
Then take antiderivatives, etc.

Comment: Your second expression is what I included towards the end of my post as the notation that I believe is wrong. The integral includes all $x \in (-\infty, 0]$, which is a problem, because for $x < 0$ we have $e^{- |x|} = e^{x}$, but as soon as $x = 0$, we have $e^{-x}$. There is no way the integrand is being justly represented due to it having an absolute value, and the values of the integral upon which $x$ spans.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire : There's no need to worry about that.  In the first place, when $x=0$ then $-|x|$ and $-x$ and $x$ are all the same thing.  In the second place, any change in the value of a function at an isolated point does not alter the value of the integral. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the given function $$f(x)=e^{-|x|}\implies f(-x)=e^{-|-x|}=e^{-|x|}=f(x)$$ hence $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ is an even function

Now, using property of definite integral $\color{blue}{\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}dx$$
Since, $|x|=x\ \forall \ \ 0\leq x$ hence 
$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=2[-e^{-x}]_{0}^{\infty}$$ $$=2[-e^{-\infty}+e^{0}]=2[0+1]=2[1]=\color{red}{2}$$

Comment: That's fine, but that doesn't answer my question. My issue is not with how to solve it: I purposefully chose the method written in my post to ask a question.